# Flex blank/white screen after deploy

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash

Just uploaded a .war file to the server.. everthing is ok there.. but by no reason the login page is not loading anything..
i earned this flex+java projects on my new job.. its kind strange to me..
i can't even use firebug on it.. it dysplay nothing on eclipse console.
plz someone give me a hand !

The login page mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"      width="100%" height="100%" initialize="Spinner.init(this)" >
<mx:Style source="../flexdesign/css/Login.css"/>
<mx:Style source="../flexdesign/css/principal.css"/>
<mx:Style source="../flexdesign/css/conteudo.css"/>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import automacao.ui.Spinner;

        import flash.net.navigateToURL;

        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function abreMenu(url:String):void{
            try {
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url),"_parent"); 
            } catch (e:Error) {
                trace("Error occurred!");
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Move id="cimabaixo" duration="1100" yFrom="0" yTo="0" xFrom="300" xTo="0"/>
<mx:Iris id="zoom" duration="300" xFrom="0" xTo="1" yFrom="0" yTo="1"/>
<mx:Zoom id="zoomhide" duration="500" zoomWidthFrom="1" zoomWidthTo="0" zoomHeightFrom="1" zoomHeightTo="0"/>
<mx:Glow id="brilho" duration="300" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo=".4" blurXFrom="0" blurXTo="20" blurYFrom="0" blurYTo="20" color="0xBBBBBB" strength="3"/>
<mx:Glow id="sembrilho" duration="500" alphaFrom=".6" alphaTo="0" blurXFrom="20" blurXTo="0" blurYFrom="20" blurYTo="0" color="0xBBBBBB" strength="3"/>
<mx:Glow id="brilhoradio" duration="200" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo=".4" blurXFrom="0" blurXTo="15" blurYFrom="0" blurYTo="15" color="0xBBBBBB" strength="2"/>
<mx:Glow id="sembrilhoradio" duration="200" alphaFrom=".3" alphaTo="0" blurXFrom="15" blurXTo="0" blurYFrom="15" blurYTo="0" color="0xBBBBBB" strength="2"/>
<mx:Fade id="fadeOut" duration="300" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0"/>
<mx:Fade id="fadeIn" duration="300" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0"/>
<mx:ModuleLoader id="workspace" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" url="LoginView.swf"/>
  </mx:Application>
```

it was working like a piece of cake.. i just make some java business change and deploy the project..

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Flex either, but just see if any of these ideas help.

1) Restore the backup and confirm it does still work, and it's your changes. (Just get that out of the way)
2) Ensure you can find those imports on the classpath (i.e. automacao.ui.Spinner etc.)  Your WAR might not have included them for some reason.
3) Add into that abreMenu function some sort of generic output to a file to see if it's getting there.  I'll suspect its not.
4) Turn on trace-level debugging in log4j/slf4j or whatever you're using.

When you find the answer, post back. :)

Comment: im using *log4j* budy, but it's not displayin nothing.. *navigateToURL* and new *URLRequest* is flex native. i'll try to rollback.. thanks !

Comment: Let us know how it goes.

Note to self: Don't use flex ;)

Comment: im c# mvc developer dude! my boss found that i develop on java.. then u know.. earned some legacy projects.. I'll migrate these projects soon....

Answer (score 0):

Is LoginView.swf still on the same directory?
Also download the [Flash debug version](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) so that you will see the "silenced" errors.

Comment: Flash debug version.. THANKS!!
and yes, LoginView.swf is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Flex Builder, Go to Project --> Properties --> FlexModules.
Make sure you have added your module LoginView to that. This might be a reason for module not loading.

Comment: cool, it's there.. and more 5 .mxml files. maybe it's because tomcat.. im using tomcat 7.0 to emulate a server. this may be the problem.